# How do I control what's mounted at Linux startup?

Tags: fedora, mount, boot

This might sound like, an "Edit /etc/fstab" answer.  My fstab has the SD card mounted to /home directory.  However, when I start the computer, the home directory ends up on the same partition as my / directory, instead of on the SD card.

1. Mounting the SD card to any other directory (e.g. /home2) works.
2. Moving the /home entry up/down in fstab does not help.
3. Modifying parameters of the /home mount does not help.
4. Manually typing in "mount /home" at the command prompt after the computer is started does work.

Entry from cat /proc/mounts: [first one comes from fstab]

```
mtd0 on / type jffs2 (rw,noatime,rp_size=4096)
mtd0 on /home type jffs2 (rw,relatime,rp_size=4096)
mtd0 on /versions type jffs2 (rw,relatime,rp_size=4096)
mtd0 on /security type jffs2 (rw,relatime,rp_size=4096)
```

(then come remaining entries from fstab)

I have Fedora 18.  To answer comments:

After running "mount /home", the entries listed above stay; however, a new entry is added below, which results in a correct mount:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p3 /home ext3 rw,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,nodelalloc,data=ordered  0 0
```

My /etc/fstab file:

```
/dev/root   /   ext4    defaults,noatime    0 0
devpts  /dev/pts    devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
tmpfs   /dev/shm    tmpfs   defaults,size=50m   0 0
proc    /proc   proc    defaults    0 0
sysfs   /sys    sysfs   defaults    0 0
/dev/mmcblk0p2  swap    swap    0 0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /usr    ext3    defaults    0 0
/dev/mmcblk0p4  /var    ext2    defaults    0 0
/dev/mmcblk0p3  /home   ext3    defaults    0 0
```

How do I keep /home from mounting on the same partition as /?

Comment: We say "a device is mounted on a directory", not the other way round. It looks like you mount the same device to several mount points. This makes sense with file systems with subvolumes (like btrfs) only. What is the output of `cat /proc/mounts` after running `mount /home` manually?

Comment: Can you also provide the relevant lines from your fstab, all of them would be good?

Comment: @HaukeLaging OK, I updated my post.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @DougHendrick OK, I updated my post.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @drewbenn It's `root=` not `init=`

Comment: What is the output of `cat /proc/cmdline`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty0 fbcon=font:SUN12x22 no_console_suspend selinux=0

Comment: @drewbenn Yes, it is an embedded system.  The Fedora came from the factory image.  /dev/root is the FLASH device where the / filesystem is stored.

Comment: there's an fstab in initramfs, too. it will get packed in there when you build it. build a new one.

Comment: @mikeserv My /boot folder has a initrd-plymouth.img file in it (i.e., no initramfs files).  Is there a way to make sure that this is the source of the problem, before trying the solution?  If not, can you give some pointers (or, a reference) on how to build it without losing the current configuration, by posting an answer?

Comment: its initramfs. it doesn't matter what its called. if you want to see whats in there just extract it - its a cpio - its just img in your thing and so is probably not even compressed. `mkdir /tmp/initramfs && cd /tmp/initramfs || exit; set /boot/initrd*; cat=; case $(file "$1") in *zip*) cat=z;; esac; "${cat}cat" "$1"  | cpio -vid` should extract the tree in a tmpdir.

Comment: @mikeserv Your command worked; I would've given an up vote if it were an answer; however, there is no fstab in the extracted files (unless it's in the lib folder).  So I assume this means following your directions will not fix the problem?  Or might following instructions in https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/15/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Verifying_the_Initial_RAM_Disk_Image.html help me fix the problem?  In either case, you might wish to post your comment as an answer in case others have a similar problem, for which your suggestion would work.

Comment: there is an `/etc`, right? there doesn't need to be an fstab in there - and so maybe its irrelevant. but your mount process *starts* in initramfs every time. review the scripts in there. figure out what it does. the worst that'll happen is you'll learn something. it looks like you're talking about android - is it? some of the stuff looked weird in your question - and why is your home on an sd card anyway? what kind of computer is it?

Comment: @mikeserv Yes, there is an "/etc" (I don't know how to do the highlight).  It has "fedora-release" textfile with version, and plymouth directory with .conf file.  It is a Sugar-based computer, for which the manufacturer released a Fedora version.  No Android or anything involved.  Using an SD card for frequently used files just allows the hard drive (which is not replaceable) to work longer.

Comment: so its system-d then? you might have a mount unit. you can look through your system manager units with `systemctl --list-unit-files`

Comment: @mikeserv Yes, there is an active 'mounted' "home.mount" unit, in addition to several systemd services and paths.  How do I deactivate/modify it?  At this point, you definitely have enough info to post an answer I can accept.

Comment: hmmm... i dunno or don't remember. i never used those cause i didn't like them very much. lemme try to figure it out. maybe i can. oh. i guess you just do `systemctl cat home.mount` to get a printout of its contents.

Comment: probably not necessary, though. `man  systemd.mount` says that fstab takes precedence for a mount unit unless the mount unit file is in `/etc`. that means that either 1. we're on the wrong track or 2. `find /etc -name home.mount` will turn up your annoying unit file. if it does, do `systemctl disable home.mount` and your problem is solved because fstab will start to work again.

Comment: @mikeserv After some investigation: home.mount is not a unit *file*, and so it cannot be disabled/modified.  It can, however, be masked.  Even then, upon restart it shows "masked active mounted" status.  There is no home.mount file in the whole /.  I think I'll just post disabling home.mount as another question on this forum.

Comment: Search in the output of `journalctl -b` for `home` or `mount`.

Comment: @HaukeLaging The error posted from `journalctl - b` turned out to be a non-recurrent error, so I deleted it.  
The only thing its output showed was, when the entries from fstab were processed, the /home directory is totally ignored, as if it were not in the fstab.

Comment: From output of dmesg: `[11] JFFS2 notice: (103) jffs2_build_xattr_subsystem: complete building xattr subsystem, 44 of xdatum (18 unchecked, 26 orphan) and 44 of xref (0 dead, 26 orphan) found.` `[11] dracut: Mounted root filesystem mtd0`  At [14],[15] come `systemd[1]: Mounting/ed * File System`, where * is Debug, Huge Pages,  Configuration, FUSE Control, POSIX Message Queue.  At `[17]`, come the mounts from the fstab.  However, since /home is already mounted (probably at 11), then it is totally ignored there.

Comment: @mikeserv I contacted another user of this device, and he said he got around this problem by mounting `/home/username` to the SD card.  Since mapping any other directory worked, this achieved my goal of extending the lifespan of the hard drive.  So if you wish to post your list of troubleshooting steps as an answer for posterity, I can accept it.  Or if you don't have the time, you can just post copy-and-paste your comments, and I can edit the steps into it.  Just remark in the post that I may do it, so editors would accept it.

Comment: You know, in my opinion, the best answers are selfies. Especially for one-offs - my answer would just be conjecture, but it's *your* problem and *you* fixed it, so who could be better to document it than you? If you post an answer, I'll upvote it.